# how to account for non-independence in the analysis of dissimilarity matrices with restricted PERMANOVA or alternative methods

Tags: hypothesis-testing, independence, permutation, permanova

I am doing a study looking at how bacterial communities on eggshells correlate with species-site and nest stage. We sampled the eggshell bacteria at two sites, with two different host species sampled at one of those sites. As such, I have been analyzing the data with a combined species-site 3-level factor. Some of the nests at each species-site group were sampled twice, once during laying and once during incubating. I would like to determine if nest stage is an important factor for explaining the variation in the detected microbial communities, and if there is a difference in this importance in the different species-site groups.

Following guidance from [repeated measures PERMANOVA nowhere to find](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/590510/repeated-measures-permanova-nowhere-to-find) and https://uw.pressbooks.pub/appliedmultivariatestatistics/chapter/permanova/ I performed four restricted permanova tests with only my paired sample data (nests that were sampled twice) - one dissimilarity matrix with all the paired samples, then one dissimilarity matrix with the paired samples subset to each species-site group. I restricted permutations to the nest and performed a PERMANOVA like

```
p <- how(within = Within(type = "free"),
         plots = Plots(type = "none"),
         blocks = meta$nest_id,
         nperm = 999, 
         observed = TRUE)

adonis2(com_dis ~ nest_id + nest_stage, data = meta, permutations = p)
```

I am having a bit of trouble understanding how this method is able to account for the non-independence in my data (ie repeated measured at the same nest). Since the blocking structure of the restricted permutation restricts the permutations to within the nest_id, doesn't this mean that the permutations are only happening on the non-independent samples? As one of the main assumptions of PERMANOVA is that the objects being permuted are independent, doesn't this restriction of permutations violate this assumption?

Additionally I am wondering if this is an appropriate method to analyze my data. Do you have any suggestions for alternative methods or alternative ways to account for the non-independence of my samples?

Thank you for your time and help.